# How can I add to every item (string) inside of the List<int, string> dynamic id (int) which is actually position of every element inside?

Tags: c#, list

I need to add an id/key to every element inside of the `List<int, string>`.

I tried method with static id:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sen.Length; i++)
{
    mySentences.Add(new Values { ID = i, Sentence = sen[i] });
}
```

But there appears to be some problem with this method. I want to delete for example item from the middle of list, then every item under the deleted item should change it`s id to (n - 1).

So how I can apply to this dynamic id?

Comment: List<>Class have a built in  Index... so why you need another one?

Comment: @J.Salas Yeah, I know so is there a method to store this index value into the list?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I prefer to store index as an id if this possible

Comment: I could suggest you create a custom collection class that inherits List and overloads all the methods that adds or removes elements in the list. If you plan on changing the ID on individual elements, then I would suggest you to let the element implement INotifyPropertyChanged and have the collection subscribe to it and update accordingly. However, you will soon realize that this becomes very hard as you need to avoid certain infinite loop scenarios and other niche cases. I therefore recommend  you to not base the ID of the index in the collection. It creates a whole can of issues.

Comment: @ThomasAngeland Thanks for your answer. I will try it.

Comment: If you don't want to use indexes , you could use a hash map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method to reindex your List on every delete.

```
public List<Values> ReindexAfterDelete(List<Values> sen) 
    {           
        for (int i = 1; i<= sen.Count; i++) { 
            sen[i-1].ID = i;
        }
        return sen;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a reference to the list in every item you store in the list. If you access the ID property, you can just get the index of your list via `IndexOf` method from `List<T>`:

```
public class Sentence
{
   private List<Sentence> list;

   public int ID
   {
     get
     {
       return list.IndexOf(sentence);
     }
   }

   public Sentence(List<Sentence> list)
   {
      this.list = list;
   }
}
```

Usage is:

```
List<Sentence> mySentences = new List<Sentence>();
Sentence sentence  = new Sentence(mySentences)
mySentences.Add(sentence  );
```

This approach has two disadvantages: First, every access of the `ID` property is O(n), which could lead to performance issues if you have a list with many items. Second, it won't work if you add the same sentence twice to the list.

On the other hand, the big advantage is that you won't get any trouble updating the ID after every insert, remove and so on. You can rely that the `ID` is always correct.